# Проблема с reCAPTCHA

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, recaptcha

Вообщем, проблема такая: если подтверждения того, что регистрируется не бот НЕТ - reCAPTCHA не мешает выполнению кода, если же пользователь подтвердил то что он человек - reCAPTHCA наоборот не пропускает его дальше. Все должно быть совершенно наоборот, может нужно ещё что-то писать в html файл? Весь код, связанный с reCAPTCHA:

HTML:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="его не скажу"></div>
```

Css:

```
.g-recaptcha{
position: relative;
left: 50px;
top: 65px;
}
```

Comment: Что значит «не пропускает его дальше»?

Comment: Не даёт php-серверу обрабатывать данные, которые ввел пользователь

Comment: Значит, очевидно, нужен соответствующий код php-сервера в тексте вопроса

Comment: Очевидно обработать javascript'ом перед отправкой